# i want to move arrow by dragging and than want to toss/throw when i give swipe event

Tags: iphone

> In My Application I Have One Arrow Image With Fix Center and i Can rotate it by touch move method on same center but i also need to Toss/trow the arrow after doing some rotation with dragging or without doing that 
>    How Can I Put The Toss/Throw Action  in MyApplication

Thank You Very Much In/ advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your specific application, but in general it would work like this.

```
float startPos = /* touchStart */;
float endPos = /* touchEnd */
float angle = atan2f(startpos.y - endpos.y, startpos.x - endpos.x);
float force = 10;

float velocityX = cosf(angle) * force;
float velocityY = sinf(angle) * force;

/** Move object every frame using velocityX / velocityY **/
```